# Will mixing thermochromic pigments, of which one becomes transparent, result in a more faded color for the other?

Tags: pigments

I want to create a blend of thermochromic pigments, specifically a black pigment that becomes "colorless" at 100F and a red pigment that becomes "colorless" at 113F.

My desired end result would be a blend that is black up until 100, then red from ~100-113, and "colorless" above that temperature.

The description of the product in question is that it turns a "translucent white", and I'm not sure if that has the color of, say, coconut water, or something more or less transparent, and how much effect that would have on the red pigment (i.e., if it would turn pink/grayer). Also, would this depend on the medium they are dispersed in?

For reference, the pigments I am looking at are reversible leuco dyes encapsulated in polymers ~ 3-5 microns thick.

Comment: Oooh!  Promise that if you do this, you'll add some pictures.  :-)

Comment: In which way do you "want to create a blend of thermochromic pigments"? Paint a thin layer of black over a thin layer of red? Mix both paints and paint a thin layer with them? Embed them in a different medium like epoxy resin?

Comment: Hey, Max. I'm going through old questions that never received an answer. I suspect this is one where not many members have any familiarity. Were you ever able to get an answer, like from the manufacturer, or just experimenting? If you did, it would be great if you post an answer (a lot more people are likely interested in an answer than able to answer). If you're still looking for an answer, maybe we can figure out how to tweak the question to bump it, or just leave it open until the right person stumbles across it. Let me know your thoughts. Thanks.